# Large vector "Segmentation fault" error

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I have gathered a large amount of extremely useful information from other peoples' questions and answers on SO, and have searched duly for an answer to this one as well. Unfortunately I have not found a solution to this problem.

The following function to generate a list of primes:

```
void genPrimes (std::vector<int>* primesPtr, int upperBound = 10)
{
  std::ofstream log;
  log.open("log.txt");

  std::vector<int>& primesRef = *primesPtr;

  // Populate primes with non-neg reals
  for (int i = 2; i <= upperBound; i++)
    primesRef.push_back(i);
  log << "Generated reals successfully." << std::endl;
  log << primesRef.size() << std::endl;

  // Eratosthenes sieve to remove non-primes
  for (int i = 0; i < primesRef.size(); i++) {
    if (primesRef[i] == 0) continue;
    int jumpStart = primesRef[i];
    for (int jump = jumpStart; jump < primesRef.size(); jump += jumpStart) {
      if (primesRef[i+jump] == 0) continue;
      primesRef[i+jump] = 0;
    }
  }
  log << "Executed Eratosthenes Sieve successfully.\n";

  for (int i = 0; i < primesRef.size(); i++) {
    if (primesRef[i] == 0) {
      primesRef.erase(primesRef.begin() + i);
      i--;
    }
  }
  log << "Cleaned list.\n";
  log.close();
}
```

is called by:

```
  const int SIZE = 500;
  std::vector<int>* primes = new std::vector<int>[SIZE];
  genPrimes(primes, SIZE);
```

This code works well. However, when I change the value of SIZE to a larger number (say, 500000), the compiler returns a "segmentation error." I'm not familiar enough with vectors to understand the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The problem, in its fundamental form, is that you don't have enough memory.  Your program, executable, can't get enough memory from the operating system.

Comment: Aside #1: why is the first argument to `genPrimes` a pointer rather than a reference? Aside #2: why is `primes` a pointer and dynamically allocated rather than just a local variable? (aside #3: if you think these questions are related, then that's your mistake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing `primesRef[i + jump]` where `i` could be `primesRef.size() - 1` and `jump` could be `primesRef.size() - 1`, leading to an out of bounds access.

It is happening with a 500 limit, it is just that you happen to not have any bad side effects from the out of bound access at the moment.

Also note that using a `vector` here is a bad choice as every erase will have to move all of the following entries in memory.

Comment: this was exactly the problem which was causing my segmentation fault, thank you very much! I will also contemplate another build with out using a vector or handling the vector differently.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you wanted to do

```
 new std::vector<int> [500];
```

and not

```
new std::vector<int> (500);
```

In the latter case, you are specifying the size of the vector, whose location is available to you via the variable named 'primes'.

In the former, you are requesting space for 500 vectors, each sized to the default that the STL library wants.

That would be something like (on my system : 24*500 bytes). In the latter case, 500 length vector(only one vector) is what you are asking for.

EDIT: look at the usage - he needs just one vector.

std::vector& primesRef = *primesPtr;

Comment: 500 `std::vector<int>` instances shouldn't exceed stack storage limit for most environments actually.

Comment: Agreed! My point was that, given the usage of primesPtr, the questioner likely misused the allocation that resulted in a bunch of vectors as opposed to a vector of the required size. He is allocating 500000 vectors, going by his example.

Comment: Why `new` still then?? I was tempted to downvote your answer, because of still sicking for `new` when there's absolutely no justified reason to do so.

Comment: Right, I didn't go beyond the scope of the code, if indeed there is any use of placing this vector on the heap. That, we can't say for sure. But, this accidental allocation is a problem, clearly.

Comment: I created it on the heap because I'm a novice and thought since I would be (later) changing the size of the vector to a larger one, I would want it on the heap. Reality is, I am changing the size by changing a hard coded constant, no heap needed. Thanks!

Comment: Also, you are correct, I was trying to initialize a single vector with size 500000, not 500000 vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the array of vector Vs. a single vector, plus the heap requirements. This implies you don't even need a new. We were trying to decipher your intent.

Comment: Also note that the code appends an extra SIZE elements to the vector. I suspect that just having an empty vector with a `reserve` statement would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
  // Populate primes with non-neg reals
  for (int i = 2; i <= upperBound; i++)
    primesRef.push_back(i);
```

You only have N-2 elements in your vector pushed back, but then try to access an element at N-1 (i+jump).  The fact that it did not fail on 500 is just dumb luck that the memory being overwritten was not catastrophic.

Answer (score 0):

> This code works well. However, when I change the value of SIZE to a larger number (say, 500000), ...

That may blow your stack, and be to big allocated with it. You need dynamic memory allocation for all of the `std::vector<int>` instances you believe to need.

To achieve that, simply use a nested `std::vetcor` like this.

```
 std::vector<std::vector<int>> primes(SIZE);
```

instead.

But to get straight on, I seriously doubt you need number of `SIZE` vector instances to store all of the prime numbers found, but just a single one initialized like this:

```
 std::vector<int> primes(SIZE);
```

Comment: He's not even using any more than one of them. I think he meant a single vector, but thought he needed to pre-allocate its size using `[SIZE]`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, that was why I've been editing to _"you believe to need"_. The answer explains well, what's going wrong with the actual _seemingly working_ (as stated) code though.